# In R, create a new column based on the order of a 2nd column grouped by a 3rd column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

This is very similar to some other questions, but I wasn't quite satisfied with the other answers.

I have data where one column is the outcome of a Latin Square study design, where a participant had three conditions that could have come in six possible orders. I do not have a variable that indicates the order that the participant actually received the study conditions, and so need to create one myself. Here is my current and desired output using a fake example from the first three participants:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
(current <- tibble(
    participant = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    block_code = c("timed", "untimed", "practice", "untimed", "practice", "timed", "timed", "untimed", "practice")
    ))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 2
#>   participant block_code
#>         <dbl> <chr>     
#> 1           1 timed     
#> 2           1 untimed   
#> 3           1 practice  
#> 4           2 untimed   
#> 5           2 practice  
#> 6           2 timed     
#> 7           3 timed     
#> 8           3 untimed   
#> 9           3 practice
(desired <- current %>%
    mutate(order_code = c(rep("tup", 3), rep("upt", 3), rep("tup", 3))))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   participant block_code order_code
#>         <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1           1 timed      tup       
#> 2           1 untimed    tup       
#> 3           1 practice   tup       
#> 4           2 untimed    upt       
#> 5           2 practice   upt       
#> 6           2 timed      upt       
#> 7           3 timed      tup       
#> 8           3 untimed    tup       
#> 9           3 practice   tup
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Participants 1 and 3 had the same order, so they ended up with the same code.

**How can I tell R to create a new column based on the order of the `block_code` variable within a participant?**

Comment: What were the solutions you weren't satisfied with?  An obvious approach would be to collapse the `block_code` var so something like `current %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%  mutate(new = paste(substr(block_code, 1, 1), collapse = ""))` (assuming first character uniquely identifies a condition) or `current %>%  group_by(participant) %>%  mutate(new = toString(block_code))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another slightly different option is to use `summarise` so that you can drop the grouping without having to `ungroup`. Here, we group by the `participant`, then collapse together only the first letter for each group.

```
library(tidyverse)

current %>%
  group_by(participant) %>%
  summarise(
    block_code,
    order_code = paste(substr(block_code, 0, 1), collapse = ""),
    .groups = "drop"
  )
```

**Output**

```
  participant block_code order_code
        <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
1           1 timed      tup       
2           1 untimed    tup       
3           1 practice   tup       
4           2 untimed    upt       
5           2 practice   upt       
6           2 timed      upt       
7           3 timed      tup       
8           3 untimed    tup       
9           3 practice   tup
```

Or with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- as.data.table(current)

dt[, order_code := paste(substr(block_code, 0, 1), collapse = ""), by = participant]
```

Or with base R:

```
merge(current, setNames(
  aggregate(
    block_code ~ participant,
    data = current,
    FUN = \(x) paste(substr(x, 0, 1), collapse = "")
  ),
  c("participant", "order_code")
), by = "participant")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `group_by(participant)`, then create `order_code` by collapsing the first letter of each `block_code`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

(current %>% 
  group_by(participant) %>% 
  mutate(order_code = str_c(str_sub(block_code, end = 1), collapse = "")) %>% 
  ungroup())
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>   participant block_code order_code
#>         <dbl> <chr>      <chr>     
#> 1           1 timed      tup       
#> 2           1 untimed    tup       
#> 3           1 practice   tup       
#> 4           2 untimed    upt       
#> 5           2 practice   upt       
#> 6           2 timed      upt       
#> 7           3 timed      tup       
#> 8           3 untimed    tup       
#> 9           3 practice   tup
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>